# Django - IntegrityError, UNIQUE contraint failed but there are no existing records

Tags: python, django

I'm on Django 1.11.3.

I try to create an object:

```
obj = cls.objects.create(type=type, token=token, value=value)
```

...which fails with:

```
IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: intel_property.type, intel_property.token
```

I have a unique index like so:

```
unique_together = (
    ('type', 'token'),
)
```

Fair enough. Let's see what it's clashing with:

```
>> cls.objects.filter(type=type, token=token)
<QuerySet []>
```

Weird-- there are no existing records with these values.

I standardized the token field as all uppercase and the value of token is similarly uppercase, so this isn't a case-insensitivity issue. As part of troubleshooting I force-uppered all token values.

I also tried searching by token alone and it still yields empty Querysets.

If it matters, this query is deeply nested inside a series of transactions.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Is it possible that the record with the same type+token has been deleted inside an uncommitted transaction and that record can be still restored by rollback? Or a duplicate exist uncommitted in another process and it is not visible from other processes for that reason? The database backend and the configured isolation level is an important information for this question. Count the number of open database connections. Maybe some incorrectly restarted process still exists.